# Buffer overflow a simple echo program

Tags: x86-64, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I have an executable which simply inputs a string using "gets" and places it in a buffer. Using gdb the disassembly of the executable comes out to be -

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
sub    $0x40,%rsp
mov    $0x400684,%edi
call   0x400470 <puts@plt>
lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
mov    %rax,%rdi
mov    $0x0,%eax
call   0x4004a0 <gets@plt>
lea    -0x40(%rbp),%rax
mov    %rax,%rsi
mov    $0x400699,%edi
mov    $0x0,%eax 
call   0x400480 <printf@plt>
mov    $0x0,%eax
leave  
ret
```

I am trying to pass a shellcode which prints "hello world" on the console overflowing the buffer (64 Bytes) of the program. Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR), Stack Smashing Protection (SSP) and preventing the execution of code from the stack all are disabled. The inputs like "\xdf" etc which I see in tutorials all over the internet are not overwriting the return address as intended. The program is considering "", "x", "d", "f" to be separate characters. The shellcode I am using is -

```
\x90\x90\x90\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x2c\x20\x57\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x21\x0d\x0a\xdf\xff\xff\xff\x7f
```

The last 5 bytes are what I want the return address to point to i.e (0x7fffffffdf). How to achieve the desired result? Thanks!

Comment: A `call rel32` to printf's PLT entry is not going to work when injected at a different address (e.g. on the stack); it will be a different distance away from the target, so the branch target will be different when it actually executes.  The absolute pointers to string data are also a problem; `0x400699` in the vulnerable program you're injecting into very likely doesn't have a useful format string there.

Comment: Hexdumping compiler output is a non-starter for shellcode; write position-independent code in asm that uses `syscall` directly, and which is self-contained (not using separate `.rodata` or `.data`.)  e.g. generate data on the stack from immediates, or jump over it and LEA a pointer to it.